# React Native Expo - Play audio directly from websocket

Tags: react-native, audio, websocket, expo

I'm using react native expo and have a websocket server from which I get live audio Data in mulaw format. I'm trying to convert these data into a wav file and then play it through Expo Audio.

I use the [WaveFile](https://github.com/rochars/wavefile) Package to convert the File and would like to store it in Cache so Expo Audio can play it. (Audio can't be played from Buffer directly, right?)

Problem: Expo FileSystem only allow me to write String Files and I can't create a wav file out of the given buffer from WaveFile Package. Any Ideas what I could do here?

Answer (score 0):

```
var fileUri = `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}/test.wav`;
await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(fileUri, "UklGRsBCDQBXQVZFZm10IBAAAAABAAEAQB8AAIA+AAACABAATElTVBoAAABJTkZPSVNGVA4AAABMYXZmNTguNDUuMTAwAGRhdGF6Qg0AAAAAAP//AAAAAAEAAgACAAIAAgAEAAMAAwAFAAYAB",
```

Comment: Adding an explanation would greatly improve your answer.